# Creating a terminal menu with a challenge

Tags: c, menu, terminal, wildcard

What I wont to do is to create a terminal menu that takes various types of arguments and place it in a array param. Under is the code: Here is some trouble that I have and cant find a good solution for.

if i just type 'list' I will get Not a valid command, I have to type “list “ (list and space). 
Menu choice new should be like this: new “My name is hello”. param[0] = new and param[1] = My name is hello , (sow I can create a message with spaces).

How can I accomplish this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int menu()
{
    printf(">");

    char line[LINE_MAX];
    int i = 0;
    char *param[4];

    while(fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin) != NULL) {
        param[i++] = strtok(line, " \n");

        if(param[0] != NULL) {
            char *argument;

            while((argument = strtok(NULL, "\n")) != NULL) {
                param[i++] = argument;
            }
        }

        if(strcmp(param[0], "new") == 0) {
            //new(param[1]);
            menu();

        } else if(strcmp(param[0], "list") == 0) {
            //list();
            menu();

        } else {
            printf("Not a valid command.\n\n");
            menu();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're delimiting on " ".

`fgets` reads the ENTER.

So, when you type "listENTER" and tokenise at spaces you get one token, namely "listENTER". Later you compare with "list" and, of course, it doesn't match.

Try

```
strtok(line, " \n"); /* maybe include tabs too? */
```

PS. Why are you calling `menu` recursively? You already have a `while` in the function ...

Comment: thanks. This will solve one of the problems! How can I get the menu to put all between "this, even if there is space her" into param[] ?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question ... you need to review `param`. It has space for 4 pointers; your string has much more than 4 tokens.

Comment: You have misunderstood. given following command: new "my name is" , param[0] = new, param [1] = my name is.

Comment: Ah! Indeed I did misunderstand. My first thought was to use `strchr` ... but ask a new question: that's a little tougher :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is param[i++] = strtok(line, " "); will only split on space, not on \n (newline).  Try adding this to your array of delimeters.

Oh, and congratulations for some decent looking code that's clean and well formatted.  A pleasant change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this causes your problem but these lines

```
        /*new(param[1]);

        /*list();
```

Start a comment that is never terminated.

If you want one line comments you can use:

```
       // comment
```

(atleast in C++ and from C99 on)

But comments starting with `/*`must be ended with a `*/`and not nested:

```
/* comment */

/* also multi line
   allowed */
```

Since you start a comment in a comment your compiler should have emmited a warning, actually this shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: Hmm now it got edited away ... but what if its somehow related to the cause of the problem??

Comment: Hi.. SOrry, my fault, is right now. I commented out these functions sow you can compile the code.

Comment: sorry about the edit. The program above suffers from many problems (including program logic) and changing those comments is necessary. But no relation to the question: the question asked about stuff hapenning before the lines with the comments.

Comment: I cant really get the point/ understanding on how to divide this commando into 2 param: new "my name is"

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to type "list " is that your first `strtok` tokenizes until a space character, so you need to enter one in this case. Try allowing both `'\n'` and space as separators, i.e. replace the second parameter of `strtok` with `" \n"`.

As for quotes, you need to re-combine parameters starting from the one beginning with a quote to the one ending with one by replacing the characters in between them with spaces. Or do away with `strtok` and parse by manually iterating through the characters in `line`.